# 8bit Quantization: Prediction outputs uncorrelated to underlying model

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, quantization, tflite, 8-bit

I  quantized a basic TFLite regression model to int8 but the prediction output seems to be highly uncorrelated with the actual underlying model prior to quantizing it.

All the code and steps taken to train and quantize the model are seen below to make it easy to replicate the issue (just copy and paste it :).

I am working with the famous boston_housing dataset, which can be downloaded here https://www.kaggle.com/code/prasadperera/the-boston-housing-dataset/input

The steps I took are as follows:

1. Trained the linear regression model without quantization (which worked fine)
2. Created a new quantization aware model using the previous model
   3)Converted the quantization-aware model to TFlite (setting the input and output tensor to int8)
3. Converted the validation dataset to int8
4. Used  the quantized model to make predictions (predictions are  significantly off and seem uncorrelated to the underlying model)

i

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
# load data
dataset = loadtxt('boston_housing.csv', delimiter=",")
# split into inputs and outputs
dataset_x = dataset[:, :-1]
dataset_y = dataset[:, -1]


dataset_x = np.float32(dataset_x )
dataset_y = np.float32(dataset_y )

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
training_dataset_x, test_dataset_x, training_dataset_y, test_dataset_y = train_test_split(dataset_x, dataset_y, test_size = 0.20)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = 13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
hist = model.fit(training_dataset_x, training_dataset_y, batch_size=32, epochs=500, validation_split=0.2)


#Quantize the model
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model
q_aware_model = quantize_model(model)

# 'quantize_model' requires a recompile
q_aware_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['mae'])

q_aware_model.summary()
 history = q_aware_model.fit(training_dataset_x, training_dataset_y, batch_size=32, epochs=500, validation_split=0.2)

print(test_dataset_y[1])
print(q_aware_model.predict(test_dataset_x[1].reshape(1, -1)))







#Convert the model to TFLite
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a converter
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(q_aware_model)

 # Indicate that you want to perform default optimizations,
 # which include quantization
 converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

 # Define a generator function that provides your test data's numpy arrays
 def representative_data_gen():
     for i in range(10500):
         yield [test_dataset_x[i:i+1]]

 # Use the generator function to guide the quantization process
 converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

 # Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
 converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

  # Set the input and output tensors to int8
  converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
  converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

 # Convert the model
 tflite_model = converter.convert()

  # Save the model to disk
  open("q_aware_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)


 





 #Testing the quantized model

 # Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
 interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="q_aware_model.tflite")
 interpreter.allocate_tensors()


  # Get input and output tensors.
  input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
  output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

  print(input_details)
  print(output_details )

  test_x1 = (test_dataset_x-128).astype(np.int8)
  print(test_x1)




  predictions=[]
  for i in range(len(test_x1)):
      test_values = np.expand_dims(test_x1[i].flatten(), axis=0)

      # Set the value for the input tensor
      interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], test_values)

      # Run the inference
      interpreter.invoke()

      output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
      predictions.append(output)


  
  print(predictions) ### prediction values = 50-127, expected values 0-40
```

Comment: `test_x1 = (test_dataset_x-128).astype(np.int8)` seems off, reading [TensorFlow Lite 8-bit quantization specification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec). The mapping is not necessarily as simple as subtracting 128 and it can largely depend on your specific data distribution.

Comment: @VonC Even if i set it as default `test_x1 = (test_dataset_x).astype(np.int8)` without -128 part , My predictions do not seem correlated with my underlying model

Comment: But, using Int8 ranges from -128 to 127, and converting your float values directly to int8 could result in a lot of data loss due to truncation. This might explain why your predictions are not correlated with the underlying model.

Comment: @VonC Most of my data comprises low values on purposes so I thought it would still work after quantizing and converting to tflite model. Especially when bearing in mind that I am playing with a toy dataset. Can you point out how I can fix this please. I would really appreciate this

Comment: Can you check if your current data is indeed between the int8 range (-128 to 127)? What is `np.min(training_dataset_x)` and `np.max(training_dataset_x)`?

Comment: @VonC The output data is between -127 to 128, even before quantization the actual predicted values are low values, to begin with. But the quantized 8bit model prediction does not correspond with the original model. The prediction outputs are between -127 and 128, but the prediction values are extremely sporadic. if you run the above model you'll quickly be able to tell

Comment: @VonC Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure: the problem might not be with data scaling or quantization, but with how the quantized model is being used for prediction. TensorFlow Lite models work a bit differently from regular Keras models, and there might be some details in your inference code that could be causing this issue.